# Googlemaps API with a QT QWebView

Tags: javascript, qt, google-maps, pyqt4, pyqt5

I've been experimenting with the googlemaps javascript API.

My aim is to plot a polyline on a map.

I found the following tutorial -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

When I implemented it in a web-browser it worked, however, attempting to do the same within a QT QWebView widget didn't work. The map displayed OK, but the polylines were not plotted.

I'm wondering whether you have to be logged in to your google account in order for your googlemaps API Key to be deemed valid? i.e. it wants to pair an API to a user?

Could that be why the browser works but the QWebView doesn't?

On the python side:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(g3ui, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.initMap()
```

...

```
def initMap(self):
    self.webView.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)

    self.webView.load(QUrl('polyline.html'))
```

webView created in qt designer, relevant snippet:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

...
        self.webView = QtWebKit.QWebView(self.tab_10)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 1121, 401))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(_fromUtf8("about:blank")))
        self.webView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("webView"))
```

On the html side (polyline.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of
      // the first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and Brisbane,
      // Australia which was made by Charles Kingsford Smith.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          <!-- zoom: 10, -->
          <!-- center: {lat: 50.8548, lng: 1.1866},       -->
          center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var flightPlanCoordinates = [
          {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
          {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
          {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
          {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
        ];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6Hzn6vaW5MOn-rh9c4kenP8jBpL7rzbQ&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the simple polyline tutorial taken from the googlemaps javascript API tutorial site.

Update in response to code in eyllanesc answer:

This is what I see when running the simple main.py code:

[image: simple polyline on a googlemap in QWebView]

Comment: Show your code. Qt4 or Qt5?

Comment: OP update with relevant code snippets..

Comment: I have tried the link code in the html and it works, but the html that you show only draws a marker, you do not draw a polyline

Comment: ah sorry about that, let me update the OP a touch, I've been experimenting with both..

Comment: In your test, is the map drawn?

Comment: your key is valid?

Comment: In my QT app the map is drawn, and of the right location, but i don't see the polyline. Just loading polyline.html into my browser works polyline and all which suggests the key is valid

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: Load polyline.html into browser and everything works. Load polyline.html via my pyQT4 app and map is drawn but polyline is not drawn

Comment: try with my answer

Comment: emacs on ubuntu - i'm looking into updating my pyqt4 packages, maybe something is broken?

Comment: yes makes me think there is a problem with my installation

Comment: very good point - i think the python install is from anaconda or miniconda - will have to check my notes

Comment: oh man - i've done something incredibly stupid! forgot the shebangs on the simple example files and was running those .py files as $ ./file.py at the same time as having a binary called import on my PATH! so you can guess what import sys was trying to do.. many apologies hopefully back to the *actual* problem now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your error is caused because you have not passed a valid url, assuming that the .html is in the same folder of the .py I propose the following solution:

```
.
├── main.py
└── polyline.html
```

Code:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebView()
    view.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
    view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('polyline.html')))  
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

I have rewritten the same code for PyQt5:

**WebKit:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
from PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebView()
    view.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
    view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('polyline.html')))  
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**WebEngine:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
    view.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(QDir.current().absoluteFilePath('polyline.html')))  
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the following [link](https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/51859b839d4f25dfbc761d368d7d289c) you will find the complete code

Comment: Many thanks. When I attempt to run main.py I just get a strange '+' mouse pointer. No app appears. When I left-click I get some error msgs - have included them in the OP

Comment: Really bizarre as your code looks great. Really confused as to what is happening here..

Comment: @bph it seems that it is a coding problem of the editor, you could write back my code with your IDE since they are few lines.

Comment: your main.py is now running, but I see the same as in my pyqt UI. A map is drawn, but the red polyline is not drawn.

Comment: do i have to install anything javascript related to get this to work with pyqt4?

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the OP so you can see exactly whats going on.

Comment: I wonder if I have the right kind of API key? Are they different for a browser as opposed to an app? I obtained mine here -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: @bph Run it from the terminal and tell me if you receive any message in the terminal ?, I could help you through teamviewer.

Comment: @bph They are the same, I have placed my api in my example.

Comment: no error msgs when run from terminal - is there some other way of seeing if javascript errors are getting reported? something like -> self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True)

Comment: The API keys in both your polyline.html file and my polyline.html file both draw the red polyline when loaded in a browser (firefox in this case). Have added a screenshot to demonstrate..

Comment: @bph Yes, enable that configuration, right click before the map is loaded and select Inspect, then check the Network and Console tab, check if you have an error message.

Comment: @bph Are you using my api key ?, I had problems using your api.

Comment: yes - wasn't totally sure whether your supposed to publish API keys so I changed a few characters in the OP code. I'm confident my API key works due to my version of polyline.html behaving correctly in firefox - see additional screenshot in the OP

Comment: @bph I published my API KEY because after I will delete it, I can not help but it is by teamviewer since I need to test the code on your pc, because in mine it works correctly, maybe you have firewalls enabled, etc, and that depends a lot of your pc.

Comment: checked the network and console tab - can't see any error messages

Comment: had another go at this today and now I do see two errors in the console tab - TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.B.bind(this)') poly.js:98
 and TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.H.bind(this)') marker.js:58

Comment: That implies that you are not downloading the .js correctly, check if your network has a firewall that prevents it from doing so. Try it somewhere else.

Comment: what port is typically used? 8080?

Comment: Yes, but as I tell you one way to discard it is using another PC or going somewhere else.

Comment: so I loaded the following url into the pyqt4 app -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple It loaded but didn't display the polyline. I noticed there were also glitches in how the rest of the page rendered. I'm wondering if the webkit is out of date. Maybe it would work if I switched to pyQt5?

Comment: do you think it may be possible to post a pyQt5 equivalent of main.py?

Comment: Okay, what version of PyQt5 do you have?

Comment: oh dear, I don't know. I did just find this though -> https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-browser/

Comment: @bph execute this code: `from PyQt5.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt5.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
from sip import SIP_VERSION_STR
print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR)
print("SIP version:", SIP_VERSION_STR)
print("PyQt version:", PYQT_VERSION_STR)`

Comment: @bph PyQt5 up to version 5.5 supports WebKit, but after that uses WebEngine, I have published both implementations.

Comment: I think my 1st step is going to be to try and get the latest version of webkit and see if that fixes things for pyqt4. I just got the version no.s for pyqt4 -> ('Qt version:', '4.8.7')
('SIP version:', '4.16.9')
('PyQt version:', '4.11.4')

Comment: thats my next step after attempting to update webkit

Comment: on the subject of pyqt5 I guess the sensible thing to do is install the latest version, which will mean also installing webengine I presume

Comment: Install the version you have at hand, some dependencies you will not find in your linux, it is advisable in your case is to install the PyQt5 from the repositories of your system, the same would say PyQt4, maybe that is the reason for your problems.

Comment: pyqt5 -> Qt version: 5.5.1
SIP version: 4.17
PyQt version: 5.5.1

Comment: would 5.5.1 be webkit or webengine? (thanks for the additional code samples BTW :)

Comment: Quick answer: try any and if you do not throw any error that is the one that you should use.

Comment: I installed pyqt5 using -> sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 but when I try and run the webengine code i get -> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_qt5.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

Comment: when I run the webkit version I get -> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_qt5.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'

Comment: Am I right in thinking I have to use python3 for pyqt5?

Comment: I'm wondering if I have to install an additional package to get webengine? maybe its not included with python3-pyqt5

Comment: install `python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`

Comment: BOOM! It works! pyqt5 with webkit is plotting the polyline as expected! @eyllanesc you are the man ;) Thanks for your patience..

Comment: Now to see if I can get it working in pyqt4 by updating the pyqt4 webkit.. this would save me having to port all of my existing app to pyqt5 from pyqt4. But I am super happy to have got the example working..

Comment: installed python3-pyside.qtwebkit and python3-pyqt4 then ran the pyqt4 main.py with python3 rather than python2.7 and it worked. installed python2.7-pyside.qtwebkit and ran the pyqt4 main.py with python 2.7 and it still didn't work. I think we can conclude that the 2.7 version of pyqt4 webkit doesn't work. I don't know if thats common knowledge, but had I known I would have saved a lot of time..